# Button text not showing after troubleshooting

Tags: ios, uibutton

I am simply creating a UIButton and the text is not showing. 
I have changed the background color to multiple colors, it is not the same color as the text. I thought maybe the font was too big, and that might have been filling the entire button, but it isn't that either. Maybe you guys can see something I can't. The button is the last block on the screen

This question was asked previously, but that solution is not working for me, as I have done some troubleshooting.

[image]

```
let createActBtn = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: btnXpos, y: btnYpos, width: btnWidth, height: btnHeight))
        createActBtn.layer.backgroundColor = ObjectiveC_Colors().color(withHexString: "525556").cgColor
        createActBtn.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        createActBtn.titleLabel!.font = UIFont(name: "Courier", size: 30)
        createActBtn.titleLabel!.textColor = UIColor.white
signUpView.addSubview(createActBtn)
```

Answer (score 0):

First; you are assigning color to layer not background, to change background color do it like  `createActBtn.backgroundColor = UIColor.black` and for setting title do it in this way
`createActBtn.setTitle("test", for: .normal)`

Your code will be

```
    let createActBtn = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: btnXpos, y: btnYpos, width: btnWidth, height: btnHeight))
    createActBtn.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
    createActBtn.titleLabel!.font = UIFont(name: "Courier", size: 30)
    createActBtn.titleLabel!.textColor = UIColor.white
    createActBtn.setTitle("test", for: .normal)
    signUpView.addSubview(createActBtn)
```

Comment: Yes, I figured it out. Sitting at the computer for hours produces rookie mistakes. Thanks.